# Cannot upload files with Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, controller, upload, laravel-blade

I have an HTML form in my blade that needs to upload a file. 
My form is like this:
function newContractor(){
let jsonResponse

```
        toast.fire({
            title: 'Contractor toevoegen',
            showCancelButton: true,
            customClass: {
                confirmButton: 'btn btn-success my-3 mx-1',
                cancelButton: 'btn btn-light my-3 mx-1'
            },
            confirmButtonText: 'Opslaan',
            cancelButtonText: 'Annuleren',
            html:
                '<form id="create" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' +
                '{{ csrf_field() }}' +
                '<label>Voornaam</label>' +
                '<input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" class="swal2-input w-100 mb-1 mt-0" placeholder="Voornaam">' +
                '<label>Achternaam</label>' +
                '<input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" class="swal2-input w-100 mb-1 mt-0" placeholder="Achternaam">' +
                '<label>Firma</label>' +
                '<input id="company" name="company"  type="text" class="swal2-input w-100 mb-1 mt-0" placeholder="Firma">' +
                '<label>Email</label>' +
                '<input id="email" name="email"  type="email" class="swal2-input w-100 mb-1 mt-0" placeholder="Email">' +
                '<label>Telefoon</label>' +
                '<input id="phone" name="phone"  type="phone" class="swal2-input w-100 mb-1 mt-0" placeholder="Telefoon">' +
                '<label>Approved</label>' +
                '<input id="approved" name="approved"  type="checkbox" class="swal2-input w-100 mb-1 mt-0" placeholder="Approved">' +
                '<div id="fileUploadField">' +
                '<label for="file">Upload a file</label>' +
                '<input type="file" name="file" class="swal2-input w-100 mb-1 mt-0">' +
                '</div>' +
                '</form>',
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            allowEscapeKey: false,
            allowEnterKey: false,
            preConfirm: (create) => {
                return $.post('/contractor/create', $('#create').serialize())
                    .done(function (response) {
                        return response
                    })
            },
        }).then(result => {
            console.log(result)
            if (result.value.status == 'success') {
                toast.fire({
                    title: 'Opgeslagen!',
                    text: `De contractor is opgeslagen!`,
                    type: 'success',
                    customClass: {
                        confirmButton: 'btn btn-light my-3 mx-1'
                    },
                    confirmButtonText: 'Sluiten',
                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                    allowEscapeKey: false,
                    allowEnterKey: false
                }).then(result =>  {
                    location.reload();
                });
            } else {
                toast.fire({
                    title: 'Er is iets fout gegaan :(',
                    text: `Sluit deze melding en probeer het opnieuw`,
                    type: 'error',
                    customClass: {
                        confirmButton: 'btn btn-light my-3 mx-1'
                    },
                    confirmButtonText: 'Sluiten',
                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                    allowEscapeKey: false,
                    allowEnterKey: false
                }).then(result =>  {
                    location.reload();
                });
            }
        });
```

My Contractor controller is using the following code to retreive the values from both the text as the file.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $contractor = new Contractor;
    $contractor->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $contractor->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $contractor->company = $request->company;
    $contractor->email = $request->email;
    $contractor->phone = $request->phone;
    $contractor->approved = $request->approved == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $file->store('public/uploads/');

    $contractor->save();

        $response = [];
        $response['status'] = 'success';
        return response()->json($response);

}
```

It needs to store the the file in the public/uploads folder. The error message that i'm getting is:
[image]

I've looked for the issue now quite a long time, and tried several things.

It probably is just something small i forgot... but i can't see it anymore unfortunatly

Edit:
I have looked at the request en saw that my File variable is not send with to the controller:

#parameters: array:6 [ 
"_token" => "XMaSZ5ZunKrs782qFXSV5AuYQ1eFCxtI5HZaEeh4" 
"firstname" => "xZC" 
"lastname" => "fD" 
"company" => "SS" 
"email" => "ASDA" 
"phone" => "SDSAD" ]

But this also seems the case for the approved field. I'm going to explore and hopefully find out why this keeps happening.

Comment: Do not post images of your code, but post the actual text (next time). Your Contractor controller contains a `$request`. Do `dd($request);`, to see what you have posted. The blade file of your form. Paste that in your original question, preferably the relevant part. I suspect you're posting your form with ajax. Show the ajax

Comment: @UnderDog Thank you for fast response. I've added the code and removed the images. 
I will check now to do the dd($request);

Comment: @UnderDog I added the dd($request) and all I got was the same error message. Call to a member function store() on null

Comment: The `$file` variable doesn't exist, which means `$request->file('file');` doesn't exist. Place `dd($request)` **above** the code of `$request->file('file');`, so you can check what's in your request, that you send to your backend

Comment: @UnderDog Thanks! is this what you mean?    #parameters: array:6 [
      "_token" => "XMaSZ5ZunKrs782qFXSV5AuYQ1eFCxtI5HZaEeh4"
      "firstname" => "xZC"
      "lastname" => "fD"
      "company" => "SS"
      "email" => "ASDA"
      "phone" => "SDSAD"
    ]

Comment: Yes and keep updating your original question with that information! See that the 'file' part is missing? That's why you get that error message.

Comment: @UnderDog Thanks! I updated the orginal question with the new information!
The problem seems to be happening in the blade field. I will try to figure out why it doesn't send the approved variable and the file variable :)